# Count the number of initialized elements in an array in C

Tags: c

My array is:

```
int array[100];
```

If I initialize the first n elements (n < 100) with integers including 0, and the rest is uninitialized, how do I calculate n?

I tried a normal while loop with the following codes:

```
int i = 0;
int count = 0;
while (a[i++])
    count++;
```

However, the problem with these codes is that it doesn't count the element of value 0 (it takes 0 as FALSE). How do I overcome this problem?

**UPDATE: below is the background of this question**

I have the following code:

```
int a[100];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
```

If I have to input (just an example):

```
1 0 1 0 1 *
```

Then the first 5 elements of the array will be: 1 0 1 0 1. The rest will be uninitialized. In this situation, how do I count the number of these initialized elements to get 5?

Comment: There is no standard way to do this. You'd be much better off keeping count of the number of initialised elements than trying to figure it out retroactively.

Comment: The problem is if it is unintialised, it is garbage and it might be an integer too.

Comment: Perhaps you have an XY problem. What do you want to achieve? Are you really speaking of initialization or of simple assignment? Is the number of initial values known at compile time? Do you need the rest of the array, those elements that are not initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't simply record how many elements have been initialized, then you need to use a "magic" value like `INT_MIN` (the largest negative `int`) to know when an element is not used.  Alternatively, instead of storing `int`s, store something like this:

```
struct element {
  int value;
  int flags; // 0 means not used
};
```

Oh, one more idea: store the count of initialized elements in the first element.  This is sort of how `malloc()` works sometimes.  Then you can make the array have 101 elements and pass `(array + 1, array[0])` to functions which expect an array of size 100.